# Gateway for StackExchange chat?

Tags: chat, web-services

StackExchange is a proprietary Q/A network owned by the Facebook guys. It provides a chat network. That chat network is chock full of experts, usually of the Slack and Discord-using varieties that can't figure out IRC.

Unfortunately though the interface is absolutely crap. I mean chatting through a web browser? No highlighting, no autojoining, no splits, no window-grouping. It's an all around hassle.

Is there any XMPP gateway I can run for this? Or something that allows me to bring the chat into irssi?